# ANDROID - How to save the contents contained in a view and recreate it when the app restarts

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Okay. I have an xml layout where it would contain programatically created linearlayout with text views and image within it. The contents are generated by the user from another activity. So, I want the programmatically generated linear layouts to be available to them when they open up the app again after closing it like for a day. In short, I want the layout information be persistently saved and be created when the user open the app again. How do I do it?

I'm confused. Should I use database, shared preferences or onSaveInstanceState? What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Let me understand. You will ask user about the layout. User enters the values the app create the layout programatically then next time it should load the layout automatically??

Comment: Yes. The app would process the info then, when the user gets out of the app and returns, the same view would be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) to save the inputted values for the layout in `onPause()`. If the user runs the app again, get these data in `onCreate()` to load the layout again.

Comment: Could you give a sample code on how to get the values for each layout consisting two text views and another linear layout?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at the [***activity lifecycle***](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) documentation.

When the activity is about to close, you can intercept the callback method `onStop()` to save the state of your Activity. When the app is recreated, you can intercept `onCreate()` to restore the state of your app.